# No suitable constructor found - (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Tags: java, maven

I'm a novice at java so please forgive if the answer is obvious. I've been tasked with converting a java project to Maven and I'm running into the below compilation error.

> no suitable constructor found for EtHttpException(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

FWIW this same error occurs in multiple other classes

**Base Class**

```
public class EtHttpException extends Exception {

private java.lang.String currentURL = null;
private java.lang.String status = null;
private java.lang.String request = null;

/**
  EtHttpException constructor comment.
*/

public EtHttpException(String status, String newCurrentURL,Exception e) {
    super(status);
    currentURL = newCurrentURL;
}

public EtHttpException(String status, String newCurrentURL, String newRequest,Exception e) {
    super(status);
    currentURL = newCurrentURL;
    request = newRequest;
}

public java.lang.String getCurrentURL() {
    return currentURL;
}

public java.lang.String getRequest() {
    return request;
}

}
```

**Error occurs here**

```
public class EtHttpsConnection {

private String sendRequest(String requestMessage, String currentURL)
    throws EtHttpException {

String responseMessage = null;
int size = 0;
int offset = 0;
int length = 400;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

try {
    setRequest(requestMessage);

    responseMessage=connect(currentURL);

    trace(currentURL);
    trace(requestMessage);
    String postRequestMessage =
        transformMessageToPostFormat(requestMessage, currentURL);

    trace(postRequestMessage);

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    String msg = e.toString();                  
    disconnect();
    throw new EtHttpException(msg, currentURL);
}
// return response
return responseMessage;

}
```

**Additional place error occurs**

> no suitable constructor found for EtHttpException(java.lang.String,< nulltype >)

```
public class NoCurrentURLException extends EtHttpException {

public NoCurrentURLException() {

    super("No current URL was retrieved from URLList", null);

}
}
```

I'm fairly sure there's one place I can make a change that will resolve these errors, can someone provide any insight?

Comment: The error message is correct. There is no constructor for `EtHttpException` that takes two `String`s as arguments. One takes two `String`s and an `Exception` objects, the other one takes three `String`s and one `Exception` object. Either add a matching constructor or fix your constructor calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no suitable constructor found for
>   EtHttpException(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

The error message is telling you that there is no constructor for EtHttpException which takes two Strings. If you look at EtHttpException, you'll see two constructors: one takes two Strings and an Exception; the other takes *three* Strings and an Exception.

You're trying to use two Strings - there is not a constructor which matches this signature.

To fix it, change the point where you throw an exception in your `EtHttpsConnection` class to:

```
throw new EtHttpException(msg, currentURL, e);
```

Then change the constructor of your `NoCurrentURLException` class to use something like this:

```
super("No current URL was retrieved from URLList", null, null);
```